# How to increase SWAP space in Ubuntu

Tags: linux

I would like to increase swap space on my existing Ubuntu machine. At present it is merely 10 % of RAM available.

I would like to make it as 50 % more than RAM.

How can I do it on a machine which is already configured ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `gparted` Live cd (or any other live cd with `gparted`) and carve out the extra space and resize the `swap` partition to whatever size you want.

Comment: Just wanted to say exactly the same thing. BTW this is IMHO rather a question for superuser or one of the other sites.

Comment: @Axel ubuntu would be my pick but I think it is going to be migrated to superuser.

Answer (score 2):

Make an empty file of the desired size,

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=swapfile count=1M bs=1k   # 1GB
```

(make sure this is owned by `root` and has permissions `0600`), then

```
mkswap swapfile
swapon swapfile
```

You need superuser rights for `swapon`. To make the swapfile persist across reboots, put it in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: You also need to call `mkswap` on the file.

Comment: If a swap already exists will this change the existing swap to be increased to 1G?

Comment: @RyanWiancko It gets increased *by* 1GB. You can have multiple swapfiles; I'm not sure what the Linux strategy for choosing between them is.

Comment: @larsmans - ah, I see, that is really cool that it can do that.  thanks